# Should you ever deploy your blank at a position other than an edge in Epigo?

Tags: openings, epigo

During the deployment step, should you ever place your Blank Epigon at any location other than an edge?

[image: Secret Deployment]

Ultimately, in this game you want to push off 3 of your opponents pieces and prevent your opponent from doing the same. Keeping your pieces off the edge just seems to be prudent. Is there ever a reason to place your Blank in the center of the board?

[image: Bad Blank Deployment][image: Good Blank Deployment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Unless I was playing a variant, I would never consider placing my blank epigon anywhere other than on a board edge.  Having 2 sides that can be attacked at the start of the game seems like a bad way to start things off to me.  I am sure there are some variants where it would be acceptable to have your blank somewhere in the middle, but not for the base game.